# How to compare two values with if statement in android

Tags: android, if-statement, retrofit, response

i try to compare two values with in if statement when one value get from server using retrofit and another value get from another fragment, if Toast is used outer if statement then show both variable values but if i try to compare those value into if statement it is not working.  Both values are same but compiler go to else part, what i do

```
public void getUserProfileData() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Api.getClient().getUserProfile(MainActivity.userId, new Callback<UserProfileResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void success(UserProfileResponse userProfileResponse, Response response) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    userEmail=userProfileResponse.getEmail();
                    String s = "";
                    if (!userProfileResponse.getLandmark().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        s = ", " + userProfileResponse.getLandmark();
                    }
                    if (userProfileResponse.getFlat().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        addressCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                        addressCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fillAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else {
                        address = userProfileResponse.getName()
                                + ", "
                                + userProfileResponse.getFlat()
                                + s
                                + ", " + userProfileResponse.getLocality()
                                + ", " + userProfileResponse.getCity()
                                + ", " + userProfileResponse.getState()
                                + ", " + userProfileResponse.getPincode()
                                + "\n" + userProfileResponse.getMobile();
                        addressCheckBox.setText(address);
                        mobileNo = userProfileResponse.getMobile();
                        pinCompare = userProfileResponse.getPincode();


                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), pincode + pinCompare, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                            if(pincode.equals(pinCompare)){           //is it correct code?
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Use **equalsIgnoreCase** instead of **equals**

Answer (score 0):

make some change in this code..

```
            if (pincode !=null && pinCompare!=null){
            if(pincode.equals(pinCompare)){           //is it correct code?
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else { //do somthing }
        }
```

Comment: You can skip `pinCompare != null`; `equals` handles a `null`parameter.

Comment: fine skiped and updated code is here, same querry for this, value of pincode and pincompare are same in this fragment but complier not entered into the equals method now till Toast showing again "failed" i can't understend what i do..

Comment: you get vale pinCompare in response if possible it has some time null. other wise you can remove from if condition.

Comment: @ Infusion Analysts ,so if i remove if statement then what condition i use, how to compare pincode value and pincompare value.